# Xcode is not using 'Header Search Path' to find my header files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, curl, xcode4, libcurl

I have just downloaded and compiled curl. In my /usr/include folder I can see folder, 'curl' and I can see that I do, indeed, have '/usr/include/curl/curl.h'. However I cannot talk XCode into looking there when compiling.

```
#import <curl/curl.h>
```

In my target's properties I have included '/usr/include' to 'Header Search Paths'. The build continues to fail stating that it cannot find 'curl/curl.h'

Am I not adding my search paths correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Angular brackets `<` and `>` are for system headers. Did you try `#import "curl/curl.h"` instead?

Comment: Yes. I did try that as well. The brackets are compiler dependent. I believe this 'should' work

Answer (score 6):

User Header Search Paths - searched for `#include "..."` and

Header Search Paths for `#include <...>`.

when we will provide its its frame work then it's class name then  Header Search Paths need to be define. `#import <framework/class.h>`

when we directly import class name form any lib then User Header Search Paths need to be `#import "class.h"`

Comment: I have added the path to both User Header Search Paths and Header Search Paths but still cannot be found.. T.T