# Xcode 7.0.1 not finding files at header search path

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-api, youtube-api

I am following [this](https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/) tutorial for upload video to YouTube.
I cloned Google library and also added path to "Header Search Path" but still it is not taking files from that location and gives me error file not found.
Then as per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431341/xcode-is-not-using-header-search-path-to-find-my-header-files) I added all that path to 'User Header Search Path' still it is not finding files.
I also select "YES" in ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS but still it gives me error.
What I am doing wrong? why "Header Search Path" is not working? 
 I am following everything as per tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the files to your project, I noticed that the tutorial suggests not copying the files to your project.  I would recommend that you remove the current library from your project, and add it again, making sure "Copy items if needed" is checked.  Them, add `$(SRCROOT)` to your "Header Search Paths" under "Target" -> "Build Settings" -> "Search Paths" and make sure the path is set to "recursive" in the drop down menu next to it.

Comment: Thank you so much @JAL, You really save my day. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried  $(SRCROOT) but it couldn't find the header

Adding this to my header search path works:

```
$(SRCROOT)/xxx.framework/Headers
```